# Javascript how to trigger dynamically created buttons?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following piece of Javascript code that works when the DOM is loaded.
But when I add new buttons dynamically (after dropzone upload), those new buttons don't respond. What should I add to this script?

```
document.querySelectorAll('.to-delete').forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Press a button!")) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'id': el.getAttribute('data-delete-attachment'),
            })

        }).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                el.closest('.columns').remove();
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
        //console.log();
    }
}));
```

Comment: You should add listeners to those buttons you're creating dynamically, i.e., as you create the buttons and add them to the DOM you need to attach onclick listeners to them with the same handler.

Comment: event delegation..... learn about it.

Comment: Duplicate [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Non-jQuery answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/5734311

Comment: @Kinglish That's not a duplicate of this question. Yours is about var and assigning event handlers in a loop (and the well known pitfall of that), and the current answer to that is to use `let` instead anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to attach the event listener to the new elements whenever you create them and add them to the DOM.

If you somehow can't modify the code that creates those elements, you could make an interval that checks for new elements every second or so, but this is of course more of a hack.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/5734311) the existing answer that offers a better way to do this. Please check for duplicates before posting answers.